# Transforming JSP from using oracle ADF faces to having simple html tags

Tags: jsp, oracle-adf

I have given a task of removing oracle adf usage from webpages and changing the project accordingly. How should go about removing adf containers and recreating UI. Is there anything i can do to reduce effort?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will be better of starting a new project from the scratch, in case your project is based on 'standard' ADF stack.

Answer (score 0):

If your project still wants to use an ADF backend and that you are just looking to simplify the HTML syntax that is generated by the ADF page, you might want to look into leveraging the af:panelGridLayout component to layout your pages rather then the various stretchable ADF Faces components.

I